# Left align location using Koma script

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script

Is it possible to left align the `place` variable using the Koma script Latex class?

I am using `scrlttr2` for letter creation. I managed to make the date left aligned using

```
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
```

However, the place `Verona, Italy` is still aligned to the right. Reading the documentation I found out that the location is formed by the date and the place variables. I tried to do the same as above to the place variable with no success. Maybe I have to set the alignment for the whole block, but I can't figure it out how. Any ideas are welcome.

The whole code is bellow.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=false,fromrule=afteraddress,enlargefirstpage=on,fontsize=12pt,fromalign=center,subject=left,parskip=full]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{utopia} 
\setkomavar{frombank}{(1234)\,567\,890}
\KOMAoption{subject}{left}
\nonfrenchspacing
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\normalsize \usekomafont{fromaddress}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{afonso@afonso}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Romeo}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{House of Montague \\ Verona}
\date{<07-03 Thu>}
\setkomavar{place}{Verona, Italy} %This should be in the left
\KOMAoption{backaddress}{false}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr 1in +\oddsidemargin\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\KOMAoption{subject}{left}
\setkomavar{subject}{Mis-shapen chaos of well-seeming forms!}

\begin{letter}{%
Juliet\\
House of Capulet\\
Verona}

\opening{Dear Juliet,}

\blindtext

\closing{Yours truly,}

\ps{PS: ``PS'' is not typeset automatically by KOMA-Script


\noindent PPS: This is a feature!}
\cc{Paris and Lawrence.}
\encl{See also The Tragedy of Romeo and Juliet}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Place in the right. It should be in the left with the date.]

Comment: `flushleft` is a list environment which introduce vertical space and needs the end command, never use the command `\flushleft` alone. Use `\raggedright` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\KOMAoption{refline}{dateleft}
```

or

```
\documentclass[
  ...
  refline=dateleft% <-
]{scrlttr2}
```

and remove your `\setkomavar {date}{...}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  foldmarks=false,
  fromrule=afteraddress,
  enlargefirstpage=on,
  fontsize=12pt,
  fromalign=center,
  %subject=left,% default
  parskip=full,
  backaddress=false,
  refline=dateleft
]{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Romeo}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{House of Montague \\ Verona}
\setkomavar{place}{Verona, Italy}
\setkomavar{frombank}{(1234)\,567\,890}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{afonso@afonso}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr 1in +\oddsidemargin\relax}
\@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{-7pt}% <- added because the head of the first page was to high
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\nonfrenchspacing
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Juliet\\House of Capulet\\Verona}
\setkomavar{subject}{Mis-shapen chaos of well-seeming forms!}
\opening{Dear Juliet,}
\blindtext
\closing{Yours truly,}
\ps{PS: ``PS'' is not typeset automatically by KOMA-Script
\noindent PPS: This is a feature!}
\cc{Paris and Lawrence.}
\encl{See also The Tragedy of Romeo and Juliet}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried using either `\KOMAoption{refline}{dateleft}` and `refline=dateleft` but I ended up getting this error: `! Package scrbase Error: option 'refline' of family 'KOMA' has no value 'dateleft'.`

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? Up to date is 3.17a and the value `dateleft` for option `refline`  was implemented in version 3.09 in january 2011.

Comment: I was indeed using an older version. I updated it and it worked! Your solution is more elegant. Thank you!